# Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "" Flutter Web en GitHub Pages

Tags: web, flutter

Estoy intentando hacer deploy de mi portafolio web en Github Pages. La aplicación corre bien en modo debug, etc.

Cuando hago deploy a GitHub Pages, me sale en la consola de Dev Tools: Error while trying to load an asset: Failed to load asset at "assets/icons/Check.svg" (404)

El output no me dice mucho...

GitHub pages link: https://bryanvazquezhdez.github.io/#/

Link de Repo: https://github.com/BryanVazquezHdez/BryanVazquezHdez.github.io

Aquí me deberían salir los iconos pero sale vacīo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y esto me dice el output:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así añadí los iconos svg:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: defaultPadding),
  child: Row(
    children: [
      SvgPicture.asset("icons/Check.svg"),
      SizedBox(
        width: defaultPadding / 2,
      ),
      Text(text)
    ],
  ),
);
```

}
}

**Asi es mi estructura de carpetas de assets:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y este es mi pubspec.yaml:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ultimo, este es mi **flutter_service_worker.js:**

```
'use strict';
const MANIFEST = 'flutter-app-manifest';
const TEMP = 'flutter-temp-cache';
const CACHE_NAME = 'flutter-app-cache';
const RESOURCES = {
  "version.json": "10cedc975dcfc8dea13d63d1520acb22",
"index.html": "d6786a1f7792fc86075eeaa66b104d8c",
"/": "d6786a1f7792fc86075eeaa66b104d8c",
"main.dart.js": "0c2f6652c5524ff0d65ee000cd308f01",
"favicon.png": "7aefa01752d1d8764c8cc0a1297741da",
"icons/Icon-192.png": "ac9a721a12bbc803b44f645561ecb1e1",
"icons/Icon-maskable-192.png": "c457ef57daa1d16f64b27b786ec2ea3c",
"icons/Icon-maskable-512.png": "301a7604d45b3e739efc881eb04896ea",
"icons/Icon-512.png": "96e752610906ba2a93c65f8abe1645f1",
"manifest.json": "6d2e5e555e8c3f34b1d1ac44e095d458",
"assets/AssetManifest.json": "7e615b4762056c06a4041bb3f99951c1",
"assets/NOTICES": "31cb9325362a5b3e6dcbc5566754e27b",
"assets/FontManifest.json": "dc3d03800ccca4601324923c0b1d6d57",
"assets/packages/cupertino_icons/assets/CupertinoIcons.ttf": "6d342eb68f170c97609e9da345464e5e",
"assets/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.otf": "7e7a6cccddf6d7b20012a548461d5d81",
"assets/assets/images/bg2.jpeg": "c6449162dc3940daa640a43101cfd66c",
"assets/assets/images/bf3.jpeg": "e65e75b1ea507f95b9378384707d2c24",
"assets/assets/images/bg4.png": "c0e535ef942f78ab808088c177843b02",
"assets/assets/images/bg.jpeg": "e08e85d27d81da280a7ef8f65f467f56",
"assets/assets/images/profile_pic.jpeg": "59114621ee3bda4c8acd1b652963ceaf",
"assets/assets/icons/github.svg": "dd01bcb52ab997575232151c45b78f8a",
"assets/assets/icons/Download.svg": "d0706912f2412b25bda8bf36e4b53139",
"assets/assets/icons/Check.svg": "1239f5832dc4ff5ac9017f34e110ab00",
"assets/assets/icons/youtube.svg": "8af4650a2939f6a2f692ce17b283a318",
"assets/assets/icons/linkedin.svg": "d36958312b1247669875963a03ce4b7f",
"assets/assets/icons/twitter.svg": "49825a69c9e7ffa9ed73d310bbf7b083",
"canvaskit/canvaskit.js": "c2b4e5f3d7a3d82aed024e7249a78487",
"canvaskit/profiling/canvaskit.js": "ae2949af4efc61d28a4a80fffa1db900",
"canvaskit/profiling/canvaskit.wasm": "95e736ab31147d1b2c7b25f11d4c32cd",
"canvaskit/canvaskit.wasm": "4b83d89d9fecbea8ca46f2f760c5a9ba"
};

// The application shell files that are downloaded before a service worker can
// start.
const CORE = [
  "/",
"main.dart.js",
"index.html",
"assets/NOTICES",
"assets/AssetManifest.json",
"assets/FontManifest.json"];
// During install, the TEMP cache is populated with the application shell files.
self.addEventListener("install", (event) => {
  self.skipWaiting();
  return event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(TEMP).then((cache) => {
      return cache.addAll(
        CORE.map((value) => new Request(value, {'cache': 'reload'})));
    })
  );
});

// During activate, the cache is populated with the temp files downloaded in
// install. If this service worker is upgrading from one with a saved
// MANIFEST, then use this to retain unchanged resource files.
self.addEventListener("activate", function(event) {
  return event.waitUntil(async function() {
    try {
      var contentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
      var tempCache = await caches.open(TEMP);
      var manifestCache = await caches.open(MANIFEST);
      var manifest = await manifestCache.match('manifest');
      // When there is no prior manifest, clear the entire cache.
      if (!manifest) {
        await caches.delete(CACHE_NAME);
        contentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
        for (var request of await tempCache.keys()) {
          var response = await tempCache.match(request);
          await contentCache.put(request, response);
        }
        await caches.delete(TEMP);
        // Save the manifest to make future upgrades efficient.
        await manifestCache.put('manifest', new Response(JSON.stringify(RESOURCES)));
        return;
      }
      var oldManifest = await manifest.json();
      var origin = self.location.origin;
      for (var request of await contentCache.keys()) {
        var key = request.url.substring(origin.length + 1);
        if (key == "") {
          key = "/";
        }
        // If a resource from the old manifest is not in the new cache, or if
        // the MD5 sum has changed, delete it. Otherwise the resource is left
        // in the cache and can be reused by the new service worker.
        if (!RESOURCES[key] || RESOURCES[key] != oldManifest[key]) {
          await contentCache.delete(request);
        }
      }
      // Populate the cache with the app shell TEMP files, potentially overwriting
      // cache files preserved above.
      for (var request of await tempCache.keys()) {
        var response = await tempCache.match(request);
        await contentCache.put(request, response);
      }
      await caches.delete(TEMP);
      // Save the manifest to make future upgrades efficient.
      await manifestCache.put('manifest', new Response(JSON.stringify(RESOURCES)));
      return;
    } catch (err) {
      // On an unhandled exception the state of the cache cannot be guaranteed.
      console.error('Failed to upgrade service worker: ' + err);
      await caches.delete(CACHE_NAME);
      await caches.delete(TEMP);
      await caches.delete(MANIFEST);
    }
  }());
});

// The fetch handler redirects requests for RESOURCE files to the service
// worker cache.
self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {
  if (event.request.method !== 'GET') {
    return;
  }
  var origin = self.location.origin;
  var key = event.request.url.substring(origin.length + 1);
  // Redirect URLs to the index.html
  if (key.indexOf('?v=') != -1) {
    key = key.split('?v=')[0];
  }
  if (event.request.url == origin || event.request.url.startsWith(origin + '/#') || key == '') {
    key = '/';
  }
  // If the URL is not the RESOURCE list then return to signal that the
  // browser should take over.
  if (!RESOURCES[key]) {
    return;
  }
  // If the URL is the index.html, perform an online-first request.
  if (key == '/') {
    return onlineFirst(event);
  }
  event.respondWith(caches.open(CACHE_NAME)
    .then((cache) =>  {
      return cache.match(event.request).then((response) => {
        // Either respond with the cached resource, or perform a fetch and
        // lazily populate the cache.
        return response || fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
          cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
          return response;
        });
      })
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // SkipWaiting can be used to immediately activate a waiting service worker.
  // This will also require a page refresh triggered by the main worker.
  if (event.data === 'skipWaiting') {
    self.skipWaiting();
    return;
  }
  if (event.data === 'downloadOffline') {
    downloadOffline();
    return;
  }
});

// Download offline will check the RESOURCES for all files not in the cache
// and populate them.
async function downloadOffline() {
  var resources = [];
  var contentCache = await caches.open(CACHE_NAME);
  var currentContent = {};
  for (var request of await contentCache.keys()) {
    var key = request.url.substring(origin.length + 1);
    if (key == "") {
      key = "/";
    }
    currentContent[key] = true;
  }
  for (var resourceKey of Object.keys(RESOURCES)) {
    if (!currentContent[resourceKey]) {
      resources.push(resourceKey);
    }
  }
  return contentCache.addAll(resources);
}

// Attempt to download the resource online before falling back to
// the offline cache.
function onlineFirst(event) {
  return event.respondWith(
    fetch(event.request).then((response) => {
      return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        cache.put(event.request, response.clone());
        return response;
      });
    }).catch((error) => {
      return caches.open(CACHE_NAME).then((cache) => {
        return cache.match(event.request).then((response) => {
          if (response != null) {
            return response;
          }
          throw error;
        });
      });
    })
  );
}
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este problema?

Aprecio su ayuda, muchas gracias!!

Comment: puedes agregar el código que usas para mostrar la imagen desde flutter?

Comment: @diegoveloper listo, ya actualicé la pregunta.

Comment: ok genial, una última pregunta, como tienes definido los assets en tu proyecto de flutter? agrega una imagen de la estructura de carpetas y otra del pubspec.yaml

Comment: @diegoveloper listo, ya actualicé la pregunta nuevamente. :D

Comment: intentaste usando  SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/Check.svg") ?

Comment: Ah ok, Diego. Lo que pasa es que en debug si se me muestra el ícono, pero en GitHub pages no. :/

Comment: podrías revisar el archivo flutter_service_worker.js generado y agregarlo a tu pregunta?

Comment: Listo, ya quedó agregado. :)

Comment: hmm ves que le agrega otro asset más? probaste con estos?   SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/Check.svg"), o  SvgPicture.asset("assets/assets/icons/Check.svg"),  ?

Comment: otra alternativa es que pruebes con SvgPicture.network en lugar de SvgPicture.asset , me cuentas como va

Answer (score 0):

Ya pude resolver el problema. Primero que nada gracias Diego por tu apoyo.

El truco fue sacar la carpeta de Icons de una carpeta que se llamaba Assets en el build de Web

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].

Así fue como resolví el problema.